# Run apk from inside android application

Tags: android, apk

I am thinking if there is a way to run an apk file and start the installation procedure from inside an already installed application.

I know that the following code opens an apk file:

```
File apkFile = new File(path + file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

but how can I find the apk(path) when it is for example inside the resources folder of the application's folder? Could this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by finding the apk path? You mean you know the file name and location but you don't know how to form its path?

Comment: Are you trying to create a malware? :) This should be restricted by system, but android has holes...

Comment: @ViktorYakunin haha no..android will ask user for the app to be installed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on whether you have your phone rooted or not, but assuming it isn't, you can put your apk file inside raw folder, open it and then run that intent. It should look something like this:

```
File tempFile = Utils.openResourceFile(context, R.raw.yourapk, "yourapkname.apk");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(tempFile),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Utils.java

```
public static File openResourceFile(Context context, int resFile, String tempFileName) throws IOException{
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(resFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(b);

        FileOutputStream fout = context.openFileOutput(tempFileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        fout.write(b);      
        fout.close();
        in.close();

        return context.getFileStreamPath(tempFileName);     
    }
```

Comment: Is this behaviour accepted by Google Store? I mean... I can use this technique inside a real world app?

Comment: @PaoloPerego I believe this is fine, because through this intent you're actually not installing an application, but invoking the package installer to ask the user, as usual, if they want to install the app.